# js await loop with promises to finish

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await

```
let array = []
for (let n = 0; n < 1000; n++){
   array.push(somePromise)
}
console.log(array.length)
```

How to modify the code, so that in line where I have console.log will be executed only after the array is filled. Filling might be async, but I am interrested in sync version as well.

Comment: `array.push(somePromise)` **somePromise** is resolved or pending promise.

Comment: `console.log` is only called when the array is populated. The promised may not have resolved yet though.

Comment: Please mention if the `somePromise` thing is a async function or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, filling is sync. Do you mean `Promise.all()`? Using `Promise.all`, you can handle some after all promises are completed.

```
let array = []
for (let n = 0; n < 1000; n++){
   array.push(somePromise)
}
Promise.all(array)
.then((res) => {
   // You can handle some here
   console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: array length would be the same before or after the promise is resolved.